# PHP: CLI stopped working error using php artisan serve with laravel4 Win7

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I've looked around SO and couldn't figure out what could be wrong with me running the php artisan serve command and getting the cli stopped working error.

I'm running WAMP and executing the command within my laravel projects folder (wamp/www/project) and get the error.

When I hit debug after Windows fails to find a solution, it shows a message saying "An unhandled win32 exception occured in php.exe [7236]"

Anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Remove windows, get linux =)

Comment: @DanFromGermany Thinking about it :P